# How to create a Checkbox on Task List that updates another column and refreshes the list

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

I'm just getting started with SP. I have SP 2010 Enterprise, full admin.
What I would like to do is add a simple checkbox column to my list. When I check the checkbox the "Status" column is marked as "Finished", and the list is refreshed.
The view I will use is to only show tasks where the "status" is not "Finished", so when I check the checkbox, the list will refresh, and the item disappear. (because it's done)
I'm pretty clear on how to create a view that only shows items where "status" is not "finished", but I'm not sure where to start on making the checkbox. I see there are "workflows", and also "ajax" stuff, but where do i start? i would like to keep it as simple as possible. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest create a Custom Action ribbon Button "mark as complete" then use CSOM to update the selected list item. That way, you could handle multiple selected items and update it once. See this blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfrost/archive/2009/11/06/adding-custom-button-to-the-sharepoint-2010-ribbon.aspx that can get you started.

If you still want to go checkbox route, that's possible too. Create a checkbox/Button on individual list item row using jQuery and pass in the ID of the selected item. You'd need to use CSOM/EcmaScript to update the item and then refresh the page. Since SP already adds a checkbox to each row, it may be confusing for users if you have multiple checkboxes.